# anonymous class constructor looping continuously

Tags: java

When i use below code, the stackoverflow exception is seen. It looks like line 16 (i.e public my m1 = new my()) is repeatedly called. Can someone please explain on the reason for calling it continuously.

```
abstract class my {
static int i = 0;
my(){

    System.out.println("my constructor " + i++);
}
public void mymethod() {
    System.out.println("Abstract");
}


public my m1 = new my() {

    public void mymethod() {
        System.out.println("Inside Abstract");
    }   
};
```

Comment: I suggest the first thing you try is stepping through the code in your debugger. This will show you the problem almost immediately, faster than an answer on SO.  If you don't know how to use your debugger, you just need to read the stack trace which will show you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance field, `m1`, which you initialize with a call to `new my`. Instance field initialization is done during construction.<sup>1</sup> So you construct an instance, and constructing that instance requires constructing another instance to assign to `m1`; constructing that instance requires constructing an instance to assign to *its* `m1`; constructing *it* requires constructing another instance, which...

You get the idea.

As [Peter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070010/anonymous-class-constructor-looping-continuously/38070130#comment63577680_38070010), by far the best way to understand how and why something is working the way it is is to use a debugger to step through the code. Using a debugger is not an advanced technique, it's a fundamental tool to learn early in the process of learning the language.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, the compiler takes instance initializer code and inserts it at the beginning of every constructor in the class. So

```
class Foo {
    private int bar = 42;

    Foo() {
        System.out.println("no args");
    }

    Foo(int arg) {
        System.out.println("one arg: " + arg);
    }
}
```

is actually compiled to

```
class Foo {
    private int bar;

    Foo() {
        bar = 42
        System.out.println("no args");
    }

    Foo(int arg) {
        bar = 42
        System.out.println("one arg: " + arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer helped me to understand, however, i have to study bit more to make myself clear.